# StackoverflowException in list

Tags: c#, list, class, infinite-loop, stack-overflow

What is wrong with this code? I keep getting a `StackOverlflowException`..

```
public class Places
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longtitude { get; set; }    


    public List<Places> allPlaces = new List<Places>
    {
        new Places { Title = "test", Content = "test\ntest", Latitude = 52.23057, Longtitude = 5.84582 },
        new Places { Title = "testt", Content = "dfsdf", Longtitude = 52.35589, Latitude = 4.92119 }
    };
}
```

Comment: You have a recursion when instantiating allPlaces. allPlaces is created when creating allPlaces.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I don't really understand. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `allPlaces` is an instance field, it is initialized during construction of a `Places` object. So you create a `Places` object, which creates a `List<Places>`, which creates another `Places` object in its collection initializer, which creates another `List<Places>` of its own... a never ending recursion.

You probably wanted to create a static `allPlaces` field, which would create only one list. Add the `static` keyword to the field as follows:

```
public static List<Places> allPlaces = ...
```

Comment: That's not an option, because I want to use the list in another class.

Comment: @user3478148: Please provide a detailed explanation of what you're trying to accomplish. It is difficult to help you if you provide so little information. Otherwise we're left to making guesses, like I did here.

Comment: I get it, I'm sorry. I'm trying to set a list in a class called Places.cs. Then I'm trying to receive the info inside the list of this class in another class, using this code:
`Places places = new Places();
foreach (var place in places.allPlaces)
{
    string test = place.Content;
}`

Comment: @user3478148: With the static field that I suggested in my answer, you can do the following anywhere in the code (from any class): `foreach (var place in Places.allPlaces)`. Notice the capital P in `Places` which denotes the class name, rather than an instance of the class. Using the type name allows accessing static members. Read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx) under the *Static Members* section.